# Test that all Python keywords are mentioned in a dictionary's values

Tags: python

I have a dict of categories of Python keywords, with lists of keywords as the values:

```
Keywords_33=[('File_2', ['with', 'as']),
             ('Module_2', ['from', 'import']),
             ('Constant_3', {'bool': ['False', 'True'],
                             'none': ['None']}),
             ('Operator_4', {'boolean_operation': {'or', 'and', 'not'},
                             'comparison': {'is'}}),
             ('Container_operation_2', ['in', 'del']),
             ('Klass_1', ['class']),
             ('Function_7',['lambda', 'def', 'pass',
                            'global', 'nonlocal',
                            'return', 'yield']),
             ('Repetition_4', ['while', 'for', 'continue', 'break']),
             ('Condition_3', ['if', 'elif', 'else']),
             ('Debug_2', ['assert', 'raise']),
             ('Exception_3', ['try', 'except', 'finally'])]
```

I want to ensure that every keyword is in a category.  This code does that:

```
from keyword import kwlist
s = str(Keywords_33)
intersection_with_kwlist = [keyword for keyword in kwlist if keyword not in s]
print(intersection_with_kwlist)
```

Expected (and actual) output:

```
[]
```

This indicates that no keywords are missing from `Keywords_33`.

Can I make this code more elegant?

Comment: An identical question has been posted at a more appropriate site (stackoverflow) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788806/check-intersection-of-two-lists - this site is not really for these sorts of questions.

Comment: It's better, but I'm still not sure what you're doing here and why you're using the names you're using. This question is going to need more context, but could turn into a mighty fine question. Please take a look at ["How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915)

Comment: I think you also have a bug. If `raise` is in the `Keywords_33`, your check says that `is` is also in it, even if it might not be, because the string contains `is`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd personally use a generic function to flatten your datatype.

1. If an item in your collection in `collections.Iterable` then you will want to recurse through it.
2. If it's not you will want to `yield` it.
3. If it's a `str` or `bytes` you'll want to `yield` it, however this can change. And so you'll want to pass a tuple of these wanted types.
4. You probably want to only go through dictionary *values* as opposed to *keys*. And so you should pass a function to handle dictionaries.

And so I'd make:

```
def flatten(obj, dict_handle=dict.keys, wanted=(str, bytes)):
    def inner(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            obj = dict_handle(obj)
        for el in obj:
            if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, wanted):
                yield from inner(el)
            else:
                yield el
    return inner(obj)
```

From this your code becomes:

```
from keyword import kwlist
import collections

unknown = set(kwlist) - set(flatten(Keywords_33, dict_handle=dict.values))
print(unknown)
```

If you don't want to remove `'File_2'` from `kwlist`, then you can always change `Keywords_33` to a dictionary:

```
unknown = set(kwlist) - set(flatten(dict(Keywords_33), dict_handle=dict.values))
print(unknown)
```

Comment: By "generic function", do you mean "generator function"?

Comment: @200_success No I mean generic, as opposed to bespoke - such as Graipher's code.

Answer (score 5):

I would make this a function that recursively steps through a dictionary:

```
def get_keywords(d):
    keywords = set()
    for x in d.values():
        if isinstance(x, str):
            # Not needed with current example, but might be helpful
            keywords.add(x)
        elif isinstance(x, (list, tuple, set)):
            # Can simply add all elements
            keywords.update(x)
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
            # Have to recurse down to get all nested keywords
            keywords.update(get_keywords(x))
        else:
            # Unrecognized type
            raise ValueError(
                "{} is of type {}, which is currently unhandled.".format(x, type(x)))
    return keywords
```

For this to work, you need to start with a dictionary, but that is quite easy with your given data structure, just pass `dict(Keywords_33)`.

Afterwards you can just do the set difference like this:

```
from keywords import kwlist

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Keywords_33 = ...
    keywords_without_category = set(kwlist) - get_keywords(dict(Keywords_33))
```

This also avoids the bug I mentioned above, namely that `"is"` is in `"raise"`, `"if"` in `"elif"`, `"or"` in `"for"`, `"as"` in `"class"` and `"assert"`, any of which might lead to false negatives.